# Adding Users To Roles in .Net 8 Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, asp.net-identity

I trying to seed my database with a default admin user and 3 roles. I am doing this in the Program.cs file. The code is as follows:

```
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var roles = new[] { "Admin", "Manager", "User" };
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            {
                IdentityRole roleRole = new IdentityRole(role);
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(roleRole);        
            }
        }

    }
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string email = "admin@admin.com";
        string password = "Pa$$word!";
        if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(email) == null)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.FirstName = "System";
            user.LastName = "Administrator";
            user.Email = email;
            user.UserName = email;
            await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        }
    }
```

When I run the app and it gets to the line where the user is being added to the admin role, I receive an error message:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "MapTest", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

This is with a new app after the initial migration. I've accomplished this with .Net 7, but having this issue with .Net 8. I can't seem to find any information regarding this or if I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas?`your text`

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint before the AddToRole method and see if the user has an Id, and if that Id matches the newly-created user in your database.  As far as I know, creating a new IdentityUser (including Application user) should create a new GUID for the Id.  So I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't want to let your Role assignment go through.

Comment: I did. And the user does have an Id. Is there a way to add a screenshot here? As I mentioned in the original post, it does work when using .Net 7.

Comment: Also, when I check the database, the user is not created. Maybe I should put in a short delay?

Comment: I just figured it out. My mistake. I forgot to set Password.RequireDigit = false

Comment: Most well coded calls like this return a result object of some type.  It's prudent to check what that is.  "await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);" returns an `IdentityResult` which contains a `Succeeded` flag and a list of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is the user manager is **NOT** creating the user. The reason is the password is not valid it has no digits. Adding `var result =`  to `await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);` would have made this more obvious.

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var email = "admin@admin.com";
    var password = "Pass123$";
    string[] roles = ["Admin", "Manager", "User"];
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
        {
            IdentityRole roleRole = new IdentityRole(role);
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(roleRole);
        }
    }
    if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(email) == null)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.UserName = email;
        user.Email = email;
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    }
}
```